# How to change location of specific keys

Tags: keyboard, hardware, shortcut

I've spilled a coffee on my keyboard, as a result right and left arrows don't function any more. Is there a way to change locations or maybe to create a shortcut to represent those keys? for example shift + up arrow = right arrow, smth like that?

Comment: You might be interested in this https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: OK, let me make that a full answer so you can give me some points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free app called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) that allows you to modify the keys.

A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for OS X.

```
You can easily customize from prepared settings.
You can also add your own settings by XML.
```

[image: karabiner]